# Show, by means of an example, that the group of symmetries of a subset X of a Euclidean space is, in general, smaller than Sym(x).

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry

**Show, by means of an example, that the group of symmetries of a subset X of a Euclidean space is, in general, smaller than Sym(x).**

Been slightly stuck on this one for a while - I'm not too sure on the exact difference between the group of symmetries and Sym(x) either. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

By definition ${\rm Sym}(X)$ is the set of all bijections $f\colon X\rightarrow X$. 
This set together with composition forms a group.
If $|X|=n$, then ${\rm Sym}(X)=S_n$ is the symmetric group with $n!$ elements. However, the group of symmetries, say , of a regular $n$-gon is the dihedral group $D_n$ of $2n$ elements. Clearly, $2n<n!$ for all $n\ge 4$.

Comment: My question is ${\rm Sym}(X)=S_n$ or ${\rm Sym}(X)\cong S_n$. if they are isomorphism how can I show it?

Comment: If $|X|=n$, then renaming the $n$ elements to $\{1,2,\ldots ,n \}$ just gives the set of all bijections of this set, which by definition is $S_n$.

Comment: We know actions of the group $G$ on the set $X$ are the same as group homomorphisms from $G$ to ${\rm Sym}(X)$, the group of permutations of $X$. For example let $\mid G\mid=24$  and $P$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. Then $\mid P\mid=8$. Consider the action on the left cosets $G/P$ by left multiplication. Then we have $G\to {\rm Sym}(G/P)$.  Actually, I wonder this: it is obvious that ${\rm Sym}(G/P)\cong S_{[G:P]}$, but how can I show it?